# Jquery adding cell in HTML table i want i set it display none as these are ids ? MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am actually adding id to HTML table than using them for saving. 
But i dont want to show it,

here is my jquery for adding cell to the table,

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
            //Reference the Name and Country TextBoxes.
            var txtName = $("#txtFamilyName");
            // var txtCountry = $("#txtCountry");

        //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
        var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0];

        //Add Row.
        var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

        //Add Name cell.


        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html($('#ddlregion').find('option:selected').text());

        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html($('#ddlcityy').find('option:selected').text());

        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(ddlcityy.value);

        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(ddltribe.value);



 //Add Button cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
            var btnRemove = $("<input />");
            btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
            btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
            btnRemove.val("Remove");
            cell.append(btnRemove);

        });
```

This jquery adding city and tribe id i want to add them but not to display.

EDITED:

```
cell.setAttribute("hidden", true); or ` cell.style.display = 'none';
```

They both are working but only for one cell

let see i change to

```
 var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(ddlcityy.value);
        cell.setAttribute("hidden", true);

        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(ddltribe.value);
        cell.setAttribute("hidden", true);
```

"Cityid" is 3 and "Tribeid" is 1 its every time hiding only tribe id not city id.
I even change variable name for both of them from cell to cell1 but result is same.

why it is only hiding tribe id ?

Comment: Simply hide that row by set to `none` like `document.getElementById(yourCell).style.display == 'none'`

Comment: how can i set its style property soon after adding it

Comment: You have `cell ` id right? pass your cell id `document.getElementById(yourCell).style.display == 'none'` just after `cell.html(ddltribe.value);`

Comment: No i dont have just adding here in my query

Comment: Try this      `cell.setAttribute("hidden", true);` or ` cell.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: So has the problem resolved?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron can you please check my edited post

Comment: Can you add some dummy data so data so that I can reproduce it. Usually no one wish to answer this kind of question due to lack of information or reproducing issue. I can assist once there is data. I had shown you idea how you could do it. that works but you cannot set as expected. If works in one node it means it can be work for both just need to know how.